# How to group fields within a column according to a certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is the query:

```
SELECT       REF.TOS                                AS [TOS Value]
        ,RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$.Percentage        AS [Birmingham]
        ,RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$.Percentage      AS [Cardiff Regus]
        ,RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$.Percentage        AS [Castlemead]
        ,RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$.Percentage        AS [Chelmsford]



 FROM       
        ( SELECT TOS FROM RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$      UNION
         SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$     UNION
         SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$       UNION
         SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$       
       ) AS REF

FULL OUTER JOIN RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$        ON REF.TOS =  
RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$.TOS
FULL OUTER JOIN RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$      ON REF.TOS =  
RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$.TOS
FULL OUTER JOIN RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$        ON REF.TOS =  
RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$.TOS
FULL OUTER JOIN RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$        ON REF.TOS =  
RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$.TOS
```

and here is the output:

```
TOS Value      Birmingham    CardiffRegus   Castlemead  Chelmsford
af11 (DSCP 10)  15.22%         4.63%          0.00%      6.16%
af12 (DSCP 12)  0.12%          NULL           NULL       NULL
af21 (DSCP 18)  0.05%          0.05%          0.00%      0.02%
af31 (DSCP 26)  8.86%          13.85%         0.01%      5.59%
af32 (DSCP 28)  NULL           NULL           NULL       0.02%
af33 (DSCP 30)  11.49%         15.44%         NULL       7.33%
af41 (DSCP 34)  0.70%          0.03%          0.01%      0.05%
cs3 (DSCP 24)   0.06%          0.11%          0.01%      0.04%
cs4 (DSCP 32)   0.15%          0.20%          NULL       0.10%
cs6 (DSCP 48)   NULL           0.23%          0.00%      NULL
defau(DSCP 0)   61.37%         61.74%         99.48%     79.78%
ef (DSCP 46)    1.91%          3.72%          0.49%      0.91%
```

I need to group certain values of the TOS Value column under a "Parent" group without affecting the other columns as they are directly related to the TOS Value Column.

see picture below for an idea of what i need to accomplish:

[image]

Comment: Avoid pictures. Not everyone can see them.

Comment: Should approach it from the other direction of self-joining each RSA_SITE table together to get the columns as needed and UNION ALL each of these queries

Comment: I don't understand the logic of how you expect to arrive at the desired result.

Comment: @tawman could you please provide me an example of your solution so i can try to implement it as i am not sure what you are advising me to do? thanks for your help!

Comment: @mxix what do you mean that you can't see the picture? is it becuse of the browser that you are using?

Comment: @RaulGonzales behind a proxy.

Comment: @mxix so am I correct to assume that you are at work? if that is the case then perhaps try accessing SO from home? and if you are at home behind a proxy maybe you need to add a rule to the proxy to allow you to see image content?  Thanks anyways for your imput.

Comment: @RaulGonzales You won't get many help with an attitude like that. Good luck.

Comment: @mxix there is no attitude, I am just giving you recommendations on how to solve your issue. thanks anyway.

Comment: The picture you have given has empty cells. what value you want in those empty cells?can you write table that is expected as output. It looks like you want to pivot the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a long-winded self-join but since this is SQL Server we can take advantage of the PIVOT table query.

[SQL Fiddle Example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fcc8/8/0)

`SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 'Birmingham' AS [SITE], REF.TOS, Percentage
    FROM  (  SELECT TOS FROM RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$     UNION
             SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$  UNION
             SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$    UNION
             SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$
           ) AS REF LEFT OUTER JOIN RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$ RSA ON RSA.TOS = REF.TOS
) BIRM
PIVOT ( SUM(Percentage)
    FOR TOS in (
        [ef (DSCP 46)],
        [af31 (DSCP 26)], [af32 (DSCP 28)], [af33 (DSCP 30)],
        [cs3 (DSCP 24)],  [cs4 (DSCP 32)],  [cs6 (DSCP 48)],
        [af41 (DSCP 34)], [af42 (DSCP 36)], [af43 (DSCP 38)],
        [af21 (DSCP 18)], [af22 (DSCP 20)], [af23 (DSCP 22)],
        [af11 (DSCP 10)], [af12 (DSCP 12)], [af13 (DSCP 14)],
        [defau(DSCP 0)])
) PIV
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 'Cardiff Regus' AS [SITE], REF.TOS, Percentage
    FROM  (  SELECT TOS FROM RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$     UNION
             SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$  UNION
             SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$    UNION
             SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$
           ) AS REF LEFT OUTER JOIN RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$ RSA ON RSA.TOS = REF.TOS
) CARD
PIVOT ( SUM(Percentage)
    FOR TOS in (
        [ef (DSCP 46)],
        [af31 (DSCP 26)], [af32 (DSCP 28)], [af33 (DSCP 30)],
        [cs3 (DSCP 24)],  [cs4 (DSCP 32)],  [cs6 (DSCP 48)],
        [af41 (DSCP 34)], [af42 (DSCP 36)], [af43 (DSCP 38)],
        [af21 (DSCP 18)], [af22 (DSCP 20)], [af23 (DSCP 22)],
        [af11 (DSCP 10)], [af12 (DSCP 12)], [af13 (DSCP 14)],
        [defau(DSCP 0)])
) PIV
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 'Castlemead' AS [SITE], REF.TOS, Percentage
    FROM  (  SELECT TOS FROM RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$     UNION
             SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$  UNION
             SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$    UNION
             SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$
           ) AS REF LEFT OUTER JOIN RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$ RSA ON RSA.TOS = REF.TOS
) CASTLE
PIVOT ( SUM(Percentage)
    FOR TOS in (
        [ef (DSCP 46)],
        [af31 (DSCP 26)], [af32 (DSCP 28)], [af33 (DSCP 30)],
        [cs3 (DSCP 24)],  [cs4 (DSCP 32)],  [cs6 (DSCP 48)],
        [af41 (DSCP 34)], [af42 (DSCP 36)], [af43 (DSCP 38)],
        [af21 (DSCP 18)], [af22 (DSCP 20)], [af23 (DSCP 22)],
        [af11 (DSCP 10)], [af12 (DSCP 12)], [af13 (DSCP 14)],
        [defau(DSCP 0)])
) PIV
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 'Chelmsford' AS [SITE], REF.TOS, Percentage
    FROM  (  SELECT TOS FROM RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$     UNION
             SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$  UNION
             SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$    UNION
             SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$
           ) AS REF LEFT OUTER JOIN RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$ RSA ON RSA.TOS = REF.TOS
) CHEM
PIVOT ( SUM(Percentage)
    FOR TOS in (
        [ef (DSCP 46)],
        [af31 (DSCP 26)], [af32 (DSCP 28)], [af33 (DSCP 30)],
        [cs3 (DSCP 24)],  [cs4 (DSCP 32)],  [cs6 (DSCP 48)],
        [af41 (DSCP 34)], [af42 (DSCP 36)], [af43 (DSCP 38)],
        [af21 (DSCP 18)], [af22 (DSCP 20)], [af23 (DSCP 22)],
        [af11 (DSCP 10)], [af12 (DSCP 12)], [af13 (DSCP 14)],
        [defau(DSCP 0)])
) PIV;`